# Is "reservee" an acceptable word like employee?

Tags: nouns

I see one reference from an old version of Webster but not much else. Word says it is misspelled.

Which is it?

> Our list of *reservees* include Beyonce, Cher, Bono...

Comment: The question isn't so much whether _reservee_ is "an acceptable word," as whether most readers will understand what it means when they encounter it in the midst of your writing. I don't think I would understand it unless the contextual clues were extremely helpful.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reservee%2Ctaupe%2Clateritious%2Ccerulean%2Cpuce&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creservee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaupe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clateritious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccerulean%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpuce%3B%2Cc0) show that it _is_ still used. But rarely.

Comment: .My guess is that somebody used a thesaurus to find a fancy sounding synonym for the word "guest" and picked "reservee", without actually knowing what the word truly means. It's a word that is sometimes used to describe people who have reserved a room in a hotel or a table at a restaurant, who are considered guests upon arrival. Sometimes, Star Performers are also called guests in television programmes, despite the fact that they serve the role of the entertainer rather than the entertained...

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260651/word-with-ee-as-a-suffix for long discussion of words formed by adding ee.

Answer (score 1):

*Reservee* is mentioned in the following:

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reservee#English)
- [CrosswordClueSolver](http://www.crosswordsolver.org/definition/r/Reservee)
- [Webster's 1913 Dictionary](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Reservee)

I've also noted that there is a considerable difference between *reservees*(noun) and the French word [réservées](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9serv%C3%A9es)(verb)

I think there is no harm in using this word when the context is clear(though it may be considered obsolete). If you're talking about MS Word, then I can safely say that the spell checker fails to recognize certain correctly spelled words(especially when the word is archaic or rarely used).

Comment: Tell me about it. I just caught it silently "correcting" the prosodic term "trimeter" to "trimester"!

Answer (score 0):

The *OED* finds one instance from 1860 and calls it "rare."  Ngram results find the use almost exclusively in US federal law dealing with Indian lands.  A "reservee" is someone who has the right to live and own property on an Indian reservation.  Better to say, "The list of people with reservations includes ...."

Answer (score 0):

The problem faced by the writer is that 'reserves,' or 'back-up,' or 'second rank' makes these stars sound a bit passé, and they might feel annoyed. So ***reservees*** is a more pretentious way of saying the same thing.

But the organisers ought to have found a better way to describe the strength in depth of their cast list.

[Strength in depth Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/strength-in-depth)

Comment: I doubt that they meant the word to mean _reserves_ as in back-ups. I presume it means _people we've reserved to perform_.

Comment: "caste list" -- intentional or unintentional pun?

Comment: @ab2 blunder. no excuses