# Word with -ee as a suffix

Tags: verbs, word-usage, suffixes, objects, er-ee

Is it correct English to be able to add the suffix *-ee* on to any verb to show the object of that verb?

Ex:

> Abandonee is "one to whom something is abandoned"
>
> Observee is "one who is observed"

I've used these in the past but what about something very obscure like one who is detected, "detectee". Are we allowed to take any verb like so and add the ending to give the verb an object?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the semantics of *-ee*. An *abandoneee* would mean someone who is abandoned. An *observee* would indeed be someone who is observed.

Comment: @peterShor Abandonee can mean both, http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abandonee

Comment: The word is _addressee_, and it applies to any utterance, not just questions. Questions have a special role for the addressee (who's sposta answer the question), but they're still addressed to the addressee.

Comment: @JohnLawler So even though some dictionaries speak otherwise, what you are saying is that the correct usage with the example above is the addressee to the abandon would be the "one to whom something is abandoned" and not the abandonee?

Comment: Ah, I see. I stuck this comment here instead of under the answer that started off with _questionees_. Sorry. Anyway, the suffix isn't very productive, and it doesn't always select objects; it selects **absolutives**, which means intransitive subject (_escapee, attendee_) or transitive object. And it can't go on just any verb, though you are of course free to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We are the [question*ee*s](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/questionee)**

Yes, but **not all verbs** can be treated this way.

### Only [transitive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm) verbs

But **you are correct**.  If you want to refer to the object of the transitive verb with only one word, then yes, all you need to do is add **-ee**

**update**

### and only with [living beings](https://books.google.com/books?id=6g0dCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA381&ots=VLyQNLavSI&dq=ee%20and%20er%20grammar%20transitive&pg=PA381#v=onepage&q=ee%20and%20er%20grammar%20transitive&f=false)

*Page 381*

Comment: Hello - No offence but large text is a bit of a pain on some portable (and wearable) devices with very small screens. Also it does look a little bit like shouting. Could you be sparing with its use? Many thanks.

Comment: I use it to highlight what I believe the question-er wants to read first.

Comment: It's an interesting non-linear technique but the usual procedure is to put the words you want people to read first at the beginning, the words you want them to read next in the middle and the words you want them to read last at the end. ;-)

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/measuring-typographical-emphasis-the-lawler-and-lawler-weight

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No.

Firstly I think your surmise is too general. Only sentient beings can have that suffix. We wouldn't say that a nail is a hammeree.

The suffix 'ee' comes from French. Initially only adopted French words used it, e.g.

fiancée (fr.) becomes fiancee (eng.)

The usage has spread but I think there's a limit. For example take the English verb "to boot". I don't think we would call someone who got booted, a 'bootee'.

> bootee
>
> 1. a baby's soft woollen shoe.
> 2. a woman's short boot.
>
> Google Dictionary

Also some words, particularly those of a German origin simply sound ridiculous if "ee" is added, e.g.

We don't seriously say that someone who has been kicked is a kickee.

EDIT

Ugh! I see that some online dictionaries do indeed have 'kickee'. I'm quite disgusted at this barbarism but there you are.

Comment: What if you were booting up a computer? Then wouldn't the computer be the bootee or is that incorrect English? Kickee may sound weird but my question relates to rather it is correct English, weird or not.

Comment: "wouldn't the computer be the bootee" All I can say is that I sincerely hope that usage never takes hold.

Comment: It would most definitely be the `bootee`.  It's just a language hack really, it can keep you from talking too long; and when people do use it, they typically use it with a questionable stress on the *ee*.  Almost as if they are unsure whether the word is correct.

Comment: Here's an odd example.  **anthropomorphize-ee**

Comment: @dockeryZ One who has a human form or personality? Finally a word I can use at parties!

Comment: @dockeryZ - Hi, You're very certain about 'bootee'. I have quite a lot to do with computers and I've never actually seen that usage. Do you have a live example? I'd be interested.

Comment: No, the computer would not be the bootee any more than a football would be the kickee or a tennis ball the hitee or a cookie the dunkee.  If you were trying to be humorous, you could call a person that you kicked, or hit, or dunked by the above words, but in that case, whether you succeeded in being funny or merely weird would depend on your delivery.

Comment: I work with computers every day and I never use *bootee* either, but it doesn't mean that it isn't a real "word"... so to speak.  it may sound extremely weird and you might look extremely weird saying it, but it's correct.

Comment: The fact that you can add it to be humorous, as @ab2 pointed out, speaks for itself.  The **communicat-ee** will still understand what's being said regardless.  Assuming English is their first language.

Comment: It's not like these are arbitrary Es.  The serve a purpose.  You can't, for instance, just add two Os to the end and expect it to mean anything.

Comment: @dockeryZ - So have I got this right? You are saying that any transitive verb whatsoever used with any direct object whatsoever can legitimately have the suffix 'ee' added?  (see my example of a nail being a hammeree)

Comment: Find me a transitive verb that you can't add it to and tell me what it is.  The word will be understood and semi-comprehensible every time.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK -  l'll admit my fault for not saying that the object must be living.

Comment: So I think that means your answer is Yes. The problem I have is that we could invent any number of arbitrary rules for making new words in English. However would it still be English when we had finished? I think it would be some weird form of pidgin.

Comment: @dockeryZ - but you have now contradicted yourself. If you agree that the object must be living, how do you justify a computer being a bootee?

Comment: Well, you can't be right *all* the time. ;-)

Comment: @dockeryZ is there a specific reason why the object must be sentient or is this just accepted?

Comment: Sentiment aside, the object must match the context of the verb, otherwise it would not be acceptable.  Just as you pointed out with `bootee`.  If the computer was **anthropomorphic**, then I suppose it would be the **bootee**.