# Word for "someone who gets helped"?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

If 'helper' means 'someone who helps', then what is 'someone who got helped'? Whom does the helper help? Is there any term to define it?

Comment: This is better asked on [ELU.se] than Linguistics, which concerns itself with inquires which span language boundaries. Language-specific questions should be amass on the language-specific stacks. (And the short answer to your question is *helpee*, at least informally).

Comment: Someone is bound to suggest "helpee."  See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260651/word-with-ee-as-a-suffix.  for extensive discussion.

Comment: You're not looking for an antonym; that means something *opposite* to helper (e.g. *hinderer*)

Comment: It's interesting because there exists the word *refugee*, for those seeking refuge - I feel like there should be a word like *aidee*.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a single word in English that means exactly what you are looking for. 'Beneficiary' can be used if the help is financial in nature, for example, or 'recipient' if the help involves giving something (object, money, advice etc.), but it depends on the context.

For a completely generic term, I think you can't get much more concise than 'one who is helped' or 'recipient of help' I'm afraid.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no financial constraint or subtext on "beneficiary". This word can naturally be used to name someone who has received help, just as "beneficence" can be used to label aid generally.  This appears to agree with the general definition provided by Merriam-Webster: *"a person, organization, etc., that is helped by something : someone or something that benefits from something."*